# With openapi codegen, how do I generate packages for pojo's?

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

In swagger spec I have models with many objects such as

org.foo.testing.MyObject

I would want this to generate code in a package org.foo.testing but instead the java and jaxrs-spec generators I've tried generate all in the same package as OrgFooTestingMyObject

I have looked and cannot find any options etc to alter this, but it seems like a simple thing that must be supported. Is there?

I've tried this with the latest openapi with the java and jaxrs-spec generators.